# Python Post to form with anti-scrape protection

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to scrape the content off a site with Python, that has a simple form authentication with username and password, but also has a hidden field called "foil" that contains what looks like a randomly generated string each time the page is loaded. In order to successfully login that value must be included in the content header of the post.  I've tried scraping out the random string after the login page loads but still redirects me back to login. I have a valid username and password for the site that works, but it is update sporadically and I would like to send myself an email when something changes.  here is the code i've been working with so far...

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib,subprocess

url='https://example.com/login.asp'

username='blah'
password='blah'

request = urllib2.Request(url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
preData = opener.open(request).readlines()
for line in preData:
    if("foil" in line):
        foils = line.split('"')
        notFoiled = foils[3]

query_args={'location':'','qstring':'','absr_ID':notFoiled,'id':username,'pin':password,'submit':'Sign In'}
requestWheader = urllib2.Request('https://example.com/login.asp')
requestWheader.add_data(urllib.urlencode(query_args))
print 'Request method after data :', requestWheader.get_method()

print
print 'OUTGOING DATA:'
print requestWheader.get_data()

print
print 'SERVER RESPONSE:'
print urllib2.urlopen(requestWheader).read()
rawRes = urllib2.urlopen(requestWheader).read()
```

The form looks like this...

```
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="https://example.com/login.asp?x=x&amp;&amp;pswd=">
<input type=hidden name="location" value="">
<input type=hidden name="qstring" value="">
<input type=hidden name="absr_ID" value="">
<input type=hidden name="foil" value="91fcMO">
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="80" size="21" value="" mask="" desc="ID" required="true">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" onClick="return checkForm(loginform)">
<input type="password" name="pin" size="6" maxlength="6" desc="Pin" required="true">
```

Comment: Why are you not passing the query string?

Comment: requestWheader.add_data(urllib.urlencode(query_args))  --> Doesn't this pass the query string?

Comment: Um, no. The query string is part of the URL.

Comment: You don't have a query string on a POST request.

Comment: A couple of anomalies. First, although the firm is POST, its action actually has some parameters. Have you tried sending those parameters in the URL, as well as your POST data?

Comment: I used the Live Http Headers plugin for firefox to watch the headers and on a successful login, those parameters in the url do not change. I did try it for the hell of it but that didn't work either.  Everything seems to happen in the content-headers as opposed to within the url.

Comment: @Ken: The "parameters" is the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import `cookielib` but it does not seem like you're using any `CookieJar`s:

```
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
```

Then use the same opener for both initial form fetching and login form submission. I assume it's a cookie-based protection where a value that comes from the `foil` field has to match a cookie that comes in the headers.

Another thing I noticed in your code is that you assign `notFoiled` to `absr_ID` instead of `foil`. Was that intentional?

Also please do yourself a favor and use `html5lib` or `BeautifulSoup` instead of parsing HTML manually.